# XBMC just stopped working, with the error: "ERROR: unable to create application, Exiting" How can I fix it?

Tags: raspbian, kodi

I just recently got my raspberry pi. I'm running NOOBS on a 16GB SD card. 
I've been running xbmc from the terminal, I ssh in from my laptop, run XBMC which is displayed on my TV.

I set up my library on a usb hard drive, and added the library to XBMC. I watched a couple of films, no problem, everything works fine. Once the app is running I'm controlling it with the android XBMC controller.

After the second film, I was playing around with the display settings, as the menus were getting very slightly clipped. Everything was fine. 
I tried to download a new skin, it appeared to be working, but when it had finished there was nothing new in the available skins. 
I tried playing another movie, but the application froze as I was navigating the menu. 
I left it for a couple of minutes but it never came back to life, so I killed the process and attempted to restart it, then I get the error:

```
ERROR: Unable to create application. Exiting
```

I've uninstalled the app and reinstalled using both:

```
sudo apt-get remove xbmc
```

and

```
sudo apt-get purge xbmc
```

But it doesn't make any difference, the error persists.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after I upgraded my Raspberry Pi to the last version with `rpi-update`.

I fixed it by deleting the contents of the XBMC temp user directory with:

```
$ rm -r ~/.xbmc/temp/*
```

**EDIT:**

If that didn't solve the problem, try to deleting the file `~/.xbmc/userdata/guisettings.xml`, but be **CAREFUL**. You **will** lose your XBMC configuration.